# c# wpf sort list of tuple<time>

Tags: c#, wpf, tuples, timepicker, xceed

i have a list of tuple filled by time.i am using xceed controls and in this case i used picktime control to get time. my tuple contains start_time,end_time,day_id
as follow:

```
List<Tuple<Xceed.Wpf.Toolkit.TimePicker, Xceed.Wpf.Toolkit.TimePicker, int>> org_time_lst = new List<Tuple<Xceed.Wpf.Toolkit.TimePicker, Xceed.Wpf.Toolkit.TimePicker, int>>();
```

and this is one example of initializing of the list

```
new Tuple<Xceed.Wpf.Toolkit.TimePicker, Xceed.Wpf.Toolkit.TimePicker, int>(mainF.sat_start_timepick,mainF.sat_end_timepick,1)
```

(in my country saturday is the first day of week :D so id for it is 1 in my case).now i want to sort this list according to start_time(item1 in tuple)

i tried some suggested method but i could not figure it out.
i did something like compare using if-else and datetime.parse(picktime.text) but here i need something like linq orderby or sort...thank you

"mainF is the mainform where timepicker exists so i initialized new form with that in its constructor"

Comment: Linq makes this easy.  example `org_time_lst.OrderBy(t=>t.Item1)`  You will need a reference added `using System.Linq`

Comment: yap ...but when i try to put the ordered list to another i get the error that says "cannot implicity convert system.linq.IOrderedEnumerable<system.Tuple<lablabalba>> to system.collection.generic.list<system.tuple<labalabalab>>" ...... List<Tuple<Xceed.Wpf.Toolkit.TimePicker, Xceed.Wpf.Toolkit.TimePicker, int>> ordered_org_time = org_time_lst.OrderBy(x => x.Item1);....

Comment: `org_time_lst.OrderBy(t=>t.Item1).ToList()` should return a list.

Comment: yes Felix ... i directly used org_time_lst.OrderBy(t=>t.Item1.Value).ToList() in my case and works..... thank you for help :)